# shorten chinesse string to fit in character array C++

Tags: c++11

I am trying to fit pinyin string in character array. for example If I have pinyin string like below.

```
string str = "转换汉字为拼音音"; // needs at least 25 bytes to store 
char destination[22];
strncpy(destination, str.c_str(), 20);
destination[21] = '\0';
```

since Chinese characters takes 3 bytes i can do strncpy(destination, str.c_str(), (20/3)*3); but if str contains any character other than Chinese (that takes 2 bytes of 4 bytes in utf8 encoding) this logic will fill.
Later If i try to convert destination to print pinyin characters, only first 6 Chinese characters are printed properly and 2 bytes are printed in hexadecimal.
Is there any way, I can shorten the string before copying to destination so that when destination is printed, proper Chinese characters are printed (without any individual hex bytes)? using POCO::Textendcoing or POCO::UTF8Encoding class?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing short of *creating own way to encode text* would work. But even in that case you would have to create 25 characters (don't forget zero at end!) array to store string at end to be printed properly, unless you create own printing routines.

I.e. amount of work required doesn't balance out win of extra 3 bytes.
Note, that code is practically C. In C++ you don't use that style of code.